# GetX onClose() runs only once

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have this call:

```
void onClose() {
    // TODO: implement onClose
    super.onClose();
    Get.find<AudioController>().player.stop();
    Get.find<AudioController>().stopFile();
  }
```

... and it triggers the first time I close the screen, but then when I get back to the same screen and leave it again it doesn't stop to play the sound file because, I think, the onClose() is not called.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried using regular Flutter behavior? StatefulWidgets do the logic you need with the "dispose" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnInit, onReady and onClose is called only once.
More info on it: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1046

Comment: Thanks! I see why this is the expected behaviour yet It's a bit of counterintuitive.